# Get local hash of package

Tags: r, github, hash

Has anyone already implemented and exported a way to get the local SHA of an R package? `devtools` (via `local_sha()`) and `packrat` do this internally, but the functionality is not exported. There are situations that [just require the hash](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/6), plain and simple.

**EDIT**: From Gabor Csardi and Jim Hester:

```
install_github("hadley/devtools")
packageDescription("devtools")$RemoteSha 
## [1] "a0c8d7333be185f979a60823dcfad66c9f3ea35e"
packageDescription("devtools")$Version
## [1] "1.13.3.9000"
```

However, neither this solution nor `devtools:::local_sha()` accounts for packages installed from the source with `install.packages("package", type = "source", repos = NULL)`.